# Importing Table form Latex to Excel.

Tags: tables, excel

Is there any way to Import a table from Latex to Excel or any other format ?

Comment: I am talking about other way round

Comment: my bad. I would then suggest a macro in Python (or any other language) that creates a `.csv` file based on the LaTeX code.
Here another way to do it manually : http://composites.blogspot.fr/2009/12/how-to-translate-table-from-latex-to.html